# jQuery index only works once

Tags: jquery

I've got a function set up to grab metadata from a provided URL on `focusout`, then use elements of that metadata (e.g. an image URL) to populate the next input in the DOM with a particular class (e.g. `article_url`). Using jQuery's `index` function to find the next input with a class, but it only seems to work once, e.g:

- Paste URL into input with class `article_id`, the function runs and populates another input with class `article_url` with image URL.
- Paste URL into second input with class `article_id`, the function runs, but does not populate second input with image URL.

Tried various permutations of `next()`, `nextAll()` and `closest()` with no luck.

```js
$('#articles-wrapper').on('focusout', '.article_id', function(events) {
  metadata_url = $(this).val();
  $.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + metadata_url)
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      meta_title = $(data).filter('meta[property="og:title"]').attr("content");
      meta_image = $(data).filter('meta[property="og:image"]').attr("content");
      meta_desc = $(data).filter('meta[property="og:description"]').attr("content");
      meta_author = $(data).filter('meta[property="og:author"]').attr("content");
      meta_date = $(data).filter('meta[property="article:published_time"]').attr("content");
      console.log(meta_title);
      console.log(meta_image);
      console.log(meta_desc);
      console.log(meta_author);
      console.log(meta_date);
      currIndex = $(this).index();
      console.log(currIndex);
      $('.article_url').eq(currIndex + 1).val(meta_image);
      $('.article_title').eq(currIndex + 1).val(meta_title);
      $('.article_desc').eq(currIndex + 1).val(meta_desc);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="articles-wrapper">
  <div class="article-item">
    <div class="article-header-wrapper">
      <div class="article-item-header">
        <h4>Article 1</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input class="lastarticle" id="lastarticle" type="checkbox" name="lastarticle">
    <label for="lastarticle" style="padding-bottom:10px;">Last article?</label>
    <label>
        Article Link
        <input type="text" class="article_id">
    </label>
    <label>
        Title
        <input type="text" class="article_title">
    </label>
    <label>
        Description
        <input type="text" class="article_desc" value="bundle://">
    </label>
    <div class="article-url-wrapper">
      <label>
          Image
          <input type="text" name="articleurl[]" class="article_url">
      </label>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd expect the function to always populate the next input in the DOM with class article_url with variable meta_image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of your `done` callback `this` doesn't reference the element that was triggered, but the config of the ajax request itself. You have to either bind the element manually by:

```
$.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + metadata_url)
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // Implementation
    }.bind(this))
```

Or you can use the `context` option in the [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method:

```
$.get({
  url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + metadata_url,
  context: this
})
```

However, `$(this).index()` will always return 0, since [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) returns

> an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

and there are no other elements in the collection. For it to work as you expect you'll have to use

```
currIndex = $('.article_id').index(this);
// No need to add one, this will find the element inside the same .article_item
$('.article_url').eq(currIndex).val(meta_image);
$('.article_title').eq(currIndex).val(meta_title);
$('.article_desc').eq(currIndex).val(meta_desc);
```

Alternatively, you can search for the elements inside the same `.article_item` by restricting the selector search scope:

```
$article = $(this).closest('.article-item');
$('.article_url', $article).val(meta_image);
// ...
```

Finally, I'd advise you to cache your jQuery objects:

```
const $data = $(data);
```

And use the `$data` variable to extract your elements, since you are constantly recreating the object every time you access it.

Comment: Great answer, really clear - thank you!